# How to set specific images for each node in dynatree

Tags: jquery, image, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

Want to know how we can able to set specific image for each node in dynatree.
I am getting one image from db as byte array in backend side and i am converting into Base64 String type and sending it through JSON object to client side and in the client side i am using it.
In javascript with the help of 
`<img src="">` 
tag we can able to display the image.

But in dynatree i saw code is like:

```
$("#navTree").dynatree({
    title: "Dyna Tree",
    imagePath: "$link.getContextPath()/jQuery/dynatree/skin-eac/",
    initAjax: {
        url: "getEmployee.do",
        data: {
            root: "source"
        }
    }
```

Image path is always taking static icon/image from pre-defined path now i want to show here dynamic image which i am getting through json object.

Can anyone please point me what exactly needs to be done.Gone through many links but not able to find out .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply a new image to the node then you can change the css style of the element while rendering the nodes using something the following:

```
$('#tree').dynatree({
    // ...
    onRender: function(node, nodeSpan) {
        $(nodeSpan)
        .find(".dynatree-icon")
        .css("background", "url(../abc/xyz.png) no-repeat");
    }
});
```